# Can I assign an element's object reference to another element's object reference within XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am implementing a carousel user interface using WPF.
When the carousel is swiped, I use a VisualStateManager to update the location of the elements within the carousel.

After I move the elements to the location of their targeted sibling's position, I want to reassign the element references so that the VisualStateManager can continue its behavior of moving items to their next position without having to maintain a journal of movements per element.

The issue that I ran into is that I believe I need to reassign element references to the reference of the sibling element that the item has just took the location of once elements within the carousel have been relocated (similar to a link list).

**Question:**

Can I assign an element's object reference to another element's object reference within XAML?
Or better yet, is there a better way to implement a carousel using XAML?

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SwipeLeftGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="SwipeLeftState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                            From="290" To="159"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                            From="20" To="73"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                            From="0" To="-25"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleY)"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                            From="0" To="-25"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                            From="0" To="-40"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                            From="0" To="20"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                            From="246" To="160"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="FrontRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            From="400" To="350"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>







                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                            From="159" To="99"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                            From="73" To="191"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                            From="0" To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                            From="0" To="2.5"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                            From="-25" To="-60"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                            From="125" To="145"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                            From="-40" To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                            From="20" To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                            From="160" To="100"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="MidLeftRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            From="350" To="100"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>










                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                            From="559" To="290"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                            From="73" To="20"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleY)"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                            To="0"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                            To="246"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            To="400"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <Int32Animation    Storyboard.TargetName="MidRightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)"
                                            To="4"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </Int32Animation>








                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                            From="774" To="559"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                                            From="191" To="73"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)"
                                            To="25"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                            From="45" To="25"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                            To="-40"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation   Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                            To="20"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                            From="100" To="160"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>

                        <DoubleAnimation    Storyboard.TargetName="RightRectangle"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            From="100" To="350"
                                            Duration="0:0:.15">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle  x:Name="FrontRectangle" Width="400" Height="246" Fill="Purple" 
                        Canvas.Left="290" Canvas.Top="20" Panel.ZIndex="4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle  x:Name="RightRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="LightBlue" 
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="774" Canvas.Top="191" Panel.ZIndex="2">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="2.5"/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="60"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-145"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle  x:Name="LeftRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="LightGreen" 
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="99" Canvas.Top="191" Panel.ZIndex="2" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="2.5"/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="-60"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="145"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle  x:Name="MidLeftRectangle" Width="350" Height="160" Fill="LightSeaGreen" 
                        Canvas.Left="159" Canvas.Top="73" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Panel.ZIndex="3" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="-25"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-25"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-40" Y="20"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>

            <Rectangle x:Name="MidRightRectangle" Width="350" Height="160" Fill="LightCoral" 
                   Canvas.Left="559" Canvas.Top="73" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Panel.ZIndex="3" >
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform AngleX="25"/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="25"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-40" Y="20"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Code:

```
private void OnSwipedLeft()
{
    var visualState = "SwipeLeftState";
    var success = VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(MyGrid, visualState, true);
    Debug.Assert(success);
}
```

Comment: You are using the `VisualStateManager` incorrectly. It was *not* designed to be used for layout purposes. What you need to do is to declare a custom `Panel` and use that as the `ItemsPanel` in a container control. See the Custom Panels section of the [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) page on MSDN for further help.

Comment: Okay. I assumed that a VisualStateManager was used for state-navigation. So the constraint of implementing a carousel my current way is that the elements within the carousel are hard-coded in XAML and not really flexible for accommodating the addition or removal of elements.

Comment: @Sheridan Considering VSM is used for layout changes like Orientation in WP and interacting with states like Visibility which could impact a layout also. I'm wondering how it could be said it's not designed for it. Maybe not in this instance (which maybe it could be if built into the templates more loosely to handle say an itemplate/itempanel via an Items supporting control instead of specific objects) but I'm confused on the statement and looking to learn.

Comment: Perhaps I could have worded that comment better.

Comment: Ok cool, had me confused for a min there, thanks man.